# DynamoDB modelling advice, duplicating a field for lookup

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I am trying to model a relationship in a sports betting app.

For a given game of sports users can predict who they think is going to win.
I am thinking about building the landing page for this app where users can view all active pools that they either own, or have participated (made a prediction in).
My data model then looks like this

[image]

So for example, we have a Pool id `a1`, owned by user `b2` with two predictions by users `b1` and `b2`.

To get all active pools owned by `a1` is simple, I just add a GSI on OwnerId and filter by IsActive.

However, I am unsure how to also get all active pools that `a1` is not an owner of, but has made a prediction for.
Would the best option here to be duplicate the IsActive flag on to the Predictions and add OwnerId to the Predictions, so I could first fetch by OwnerId and filter by `SK` startswith `Prediction` to get the Pool ids and then fetch the Pool profiles via these ids?

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking full advantage of the PK like that.

Here is how I would design the 2 entities you've described (hopefully I understood you correctly)

**Pool**

```
PK                   SK                            Other attributes
POOL_OWNER#(UserId)  Active#True#POOL_NAME(Or ID)  ...
```

This way you can

- Get all pools for a given user (Query by partition key)
- Get all active/inactive pools of a given user (Query begins with "Active =True/False)

**Prediction**

```
PK                        SK                                      Prediction attributes
PREDICTION_USER#(user id) POOL_ACTIVE#True#POOL_NAME#(pool name)  ...
```

This way you can

- Get all predictions for a user by querying the PK
- Get all predictions for a user for a specific pool + active/unactive pools

Now when "deactivating" a pool you will have to update all entries. If you are worried about data consistency you can use transactions, but keep in mind that they have a 25 items limit (but they recently [upped](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/09/amazon-dynamodb-supports-100-actions-per-transaction/) that number to 100)

If you need to get all predictions for a pool, you can add a GSI for it

```
GSI1PK                           GSI1SK
PREDICTION_POOL_NAME#(pool name) PREDICTION_USER#(user id)
```

It is not a good idea to place data that you want to use directly into the PK or SK. If for example you need the UserID don't extract it from a SK but rather have a separate attribute UserId, this way changing and overloading PK and SK is much easier

Comment: Thanks @borislav, I'm not sure this choice of PK works for me, for my landing page I would want to query all Pools that are active (games that have not ended yet) that a user owns or is participating in (has a prediction for) regardless of pool type. I don't think having a PK on pool type helps me here?

Comment: OK then, the first PK can become POOL_OWNER#(UserId). To get all pools owned by a user -> Query by partition key (POOL_OWNER), to get all pools where the user has participated in -> query by partition key (PREDICTION_USER). You will have to do 2 queries but is seems to be working?

Comment: Thanks but If I filter by Prediction_User I won't be able to know, from that query, which pool ids are active?

Comment: Oh, I see. You can then copy the active flag on both places. This will make your writing a bit harder but sometimes this is necessary when dealing with NoSQL. See my updated answer

Comment: OK cool, thanks, yep that is basically what I was guessing I would need to do in my original answer. Seems like it is unavoidable here, and indeed, sometimes necessary when using NoSQL.

Comment: Yes, it seems we came to the same conclusion.

Comment: One more question, why encode the active/inactive state in the SK, would this not be better served as a simple attribute boolean, is it for performance reasons?